# Windows Azure domain controller without virtual machine

Tags: windows, azure

I am trying to establish an RDS-Server on Windows 2012 R2 in Windows Azure. These Services require Active Directory. Until now, I created a new virtual machine and made it an ADDC. I was told there should be a way to simulate a DC with the tools Windows Azure is providing. On a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265072/azure-active-directory-as-domain-controller-for-azure-virtual-machines) a quite similar question was asked, but this one was posted half a year ago and maybe there is another way not mentioned in this post. I am trying to avoid the necessity of a complete virtual machine just to provide AD.

Thanks for your help in advance.

best regards
Jaysz

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid that!

There is no tool or service in Windows Azure that provides Domain Controller Capability. If you want AD/DC you have to maintain your own VM with appropriate server role installed.

[Windows Azure Active Directory](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/active-directory/) is Identity Management and RDS in the cloud. It can help you with developing SSO applications, but it is NOT a Domain Controler!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since it is necessary to use a dedicated machine vor ADDC, I know what I have to do!